# What are all the indeterminate forms for which L'Hopitals rule is valid?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

What are all the indeterminate forms for which L'Hopitals rule is valid? I know the basic ones are $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ and $\frac{0}{0}$. Are there any other ones?

Thanks,

Comment: It's applicable to the form $\text{ anything}\over\infty$.

Comment: Scroll down to the bottom: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: @Crostul, mate $(1)'=0$, $x'=1$ that's 0 as $x\to\infty$ which is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\frac{-\infty}{-\infty}$ of course, and you can also write $\infty \cdot 0$ as $\frac{0}{0}$ usually.